# After the Golang gin backend is deployed using Docker, upload images and request image response 404

Tags: docker, vue.js, go, web, go-gin

I have a web project that separates the front-end and back-end, using Vue3 for the front-end and Golang's gin framework for the back-end;

I have tested the corresponding interfaces before deployment and they are all normal.

Then I used Docker, compiled the backend, and deployed it on my cloud server.

I wanted to test my interface, so I tested the interface for uploading images.

Then I found that when I uploaded the image, it was normal with a response status code of 200. After the front-end upload is completed, it needs to be displayed immediately. At this time, the image requested for upload by get shows 404 not found。
[image: error 404 screenshot]

The above is the result I saw in the browser from the front-end running locally。

Here are the logs in my server container：
[image: container logs]

I have tried some methods by adding the VOLUMN command to the dockerfile to map my gin static resource directory to the corresponding directory of the server host。
[image: dockerfile screenshot]

And when running my container, use the - v option to map my host directory to the corresponding static resource directory within the container and run it.

But even after all the modifications like above, the response cannot be normal. After the upload is completed, the get request immediately returns 404

I don't know how to solve it, I can't find a way.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)  Can you [edit] the question to include the Dockerfile and log output in plain text?  If you're getting an HTTP 404 error, can you also include the relevant URL-handling code that shows what's supposed to be processing it?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have already resolved it. This is an issue with the system file path delimiter. I added a method of judging the system and concatenating paths using corresponding system path separators to solve this problem